# load data for each fieldset item Extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, store

I am trying to load data dynamically in a fieldset.

So I have a fieldset in which I dynamically add items, in my example I have two comboboxes. I want to fill those comboboxes with data coming from a store, knowing that each combobox will have different data according to its ID.

Here's what I've tried to do :

```
     var targetFieldset = targetView.down('fieldset[id=myfieldset]');
     targetFieldset .items.each(function (item) {
                                        myStore.getProxy().url ='combo_items.php?id_combo=' + item.id;
                                        myStore.autoSync = true;
                                        myStore.load({
                                         params : {
                                                        id_combo: item.id
                                                    }         
                                                    })                                      

                                    });
```

How can I do this please ? Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT** :

I have tried this as well, but it always binds the values corresponding to the last item id to all the comboboxes.

```
 targetFieldset.items.each(function (item) {
                                myStore.clearFilter(true);
                                myStore.filter('id_combo', item.id);
                                alert(item.id);
                                item.bindStore(myStore);
                                   myStore.loadData([], false);
                                    });
```

Comment: Hi, it always gives me the values corresponding to the last item ID, and it binds them to all the comboboxes. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I managed to do it by cloning the filtered store to an array and then binding that array to the fieldset items.